# What information does Google collect from long URLs?

Tags: image, google-chrome, url

Ever wondered why Google has so long URLs? I think it's because they have many info from variables from that URLs. For example, down I put the code from the Chrome logo (from the webpage that appears on Chrome browser when the web page doesn't exist. What kind of information does Google collect from this kind of long URLs? And if we discuss about long URLs, you did notice the long URLs when you search something on Google.com? They collect lots of information from a URL. Do you know any of those information from Google long URLs?

```
#logo-img {
/* "Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://theme/IDR_PRODUCT_LOGO",
so embed the resource manually. */
content: -webkit-image-set(

url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKsAAAAgCAYAAABtn4gCAAAI9klEQVR4Xu2cfYxcVRmHn3Pu3Nm6lXa2ta0AYlsgFSGgThMU0W5hGkqApNGARk3cGm3BRN3FYGuCISrBXaNphcSkG2I3hn9gY2gSNWq32AoE1C6KRihFti2QSgvsTmm783HvOa+zM69cSS8Tacsq7n2SX87cj5P7ZvLs2ztnbseICG8HMjIsbxMyMnIoxhja8fJnriuYMNdjOsIVNhd0Y0wBRbxH6nHZ16OdUot2iXNDC3/2mzJtOImOnpHJ2p4Xr13ZkDTYJLHrwRgwPJggg==') 2x);
}
```

Comment: about the url of the image above. it's not a url, it's a base64 represantation of the binary image. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a base64 encoded image. It's just the data for the chrome logo itself. Web developers sometimes embed images that way as an optimization technique. It has the advantage of saving you one HTTP request. (the HTTP headers aren't insignificant, especially for a website that gets as much traffic as google.) Unfortunately you can't cache embedded images, so there's that.

As for what the long search URLs mean, most/all of those name value pairs [are explained here.](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/614/xml_reference#request_parameters)

The long URLs were a specific decision to allow someone to copy/paste a link of results to someone else and have them see the same thing. If they just included the search query as the URL parameter and stored everything else in POST, their localized search results would be different for everyone clicking on a link.

Comment: "Google Protocol Reference" is an insight to the briliant google search code. thanks. i didn't know about this page.

Answer (score 0):

A URL consists of a path and parameters as: `path?param1=value1&param2=value2`

Furthers, URLs must adopt an accepted encoding and as such, it is not uncommon that in order to put certain characters (UTF-8, binary, etc) into a parameter-value, the data is converted to base64 (variants) or hex. The data in the URL provided in the question shows content that has been encoded in some similar scheme (note the 'base64' encoding notation) and likely represents encrypted binary content. If done properly, this allows the generator to send 'chunks' of data, using their own (common) encryption key and, when used with PKI technologies, be assured that the content was not modified in transit. This can then be re-read at any point only by the originator. Thus to answer the question, this looks like encrypted content. If AES-256 or other common (strong) encryption is being used, it is impractical to try to decipher. Generally, try simply base-64 DECODING (reverse) the content to see the raw content. If it is human-readable it may be ASCII, latin-1 or UTF-8 content underneath. If the decoded characters are indecipherable, it is probably encrypted and thus not (plausibly) readable.

Comment: for the google search result url, i know the url contains parameters, but do you know any examples what kind of parameters do they collect ? an example shown in a google url.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't collecting any information. It's just providing an image for display.

The long text is simply a base64 encoded string which contains the binary information which which would be loaded from a file. If you decode it, you'll see that it starts with a PNG header, which is what the 'image/png' is saying it should contain.

Basically, Chrome has embedded the entire content of the PNG image in the script instead of having a file stored somewhere. The comment even tells you why - "Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://theme/IDR_PRODUCT_LOGO".

A URL doesn't have to access information over the network. URLs starting 'http:' or 'ftp:' do. Those that start 'file:' access local files. And those that start 'data:' have the data itself stored in the URL.

Comment: I cannot say what Google is doing with the data but there is certainly tagging that goes on to mark advertising referrer links and other information they use in their core advertising business. As pointed out however, in this instance, the data was base64-decoded and the header revealed binary content indicating a PNG image apparently. This is the kind of research that will need to be done to decipher (if not encrypted) encoded strings (in URLs or otherwise).